# How to write data in txt file using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I am able to write the data in my txt file but I am unable to print the Barcode with "" and I want to print the text (Barcode) in double quotes.
For eg:

{"Barcode":"148279"},

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def data = [
    {"Barcode":"148279"}
]
def json_str = JsonOutput.toJson(data)
def json_beauty = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json_str)
File file = new File(filename)
file.write(json_beauty)
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot properly suggest add "barcode" question marks without knowing how exactly do you "write" your .txt file.

The most straightforward solution is considering string [concatenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation), to wit just surround the text with quotation marks and that would be it.

If you want to write a custom piece of data into a custom file during JMeter load test you should be using [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#writer) as other approaches will result into corrupt data due to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) so most probably string concatenation should do the trick for you